# rename a file in tjava component if the same file name exists in the target folder rather than replace/overwriting the existing file

Tags: java, class, sequence, talend, jobs

[image]I have a talend job which checks if the file_name and file_size exists in the database.

So as one of the cases i will be validating if for the same filename which was loaded previously (A_B.csv) if the incoming file has the different file_size (so if the file_size  differs against the database) i will be copying the incoming file as A_B_modified.csv in the target folder (provided the file A_B.csv already exists in the target folder based on the previous loaded run)

Because in the database-it adds a new entry as expected and i want to replicate the same logic in the folder directory as well,rather than overwriting/replacing the existing file-i would create a new one as A_B_Modified.csv(since file size differs here)

How do i handle this scenario?

Attached my job and tfileexist->tfilecopy condition.It is complicating the flow and errors out for certain scenario.Is there a better way to approach this using tjava code?

[image]

[image: JOB SEQUENCE]

I am using run if from the tfileexists as :
`((Boolean)globalMap.get("tFileExist_1_EXISTS"))`->if the file exists then perform the rename in such a way but it wont work precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to fully understand your question.
If the problem is the duplication of code after tFileExist_1 component, here is what you could try :

Link your tFileExist component to a tJava with an onComponentOK link.
In tJava, add a test like this one :

```
if(((Boolean)globalMap.get("tFileExist_1_EXISTS"))){
globalMap.put("myFileName",((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE"))+"_modified");}
else{
globalMap.put("myFileName",((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")));}
```

Then in your tFileCopy, you could just use `((String)globalMap.get("myFileName"))`

Comment: Thanks for the solution,i implemented a similar approach,but the thing is using (String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")) i would get the filename with extension .csv in this case then it would become A_B.CSV_MODIFIED...i want it like a_b_modified.csv 
And also i would want to validate if that filename and filesize already exists in database before iterating and using tfilecopy to move over onto the target folder.I have added one more screenshot-i feel there is no way for me to iterate after the db validation ,so i kept it as a separate job

Comment: The job screenshot on the top indicates i am checking the downloaded files in tfilelist1 against the database if entry does not exist(as per the condition "NB_LINES==0") THEN i would add an entry to the database (which is as per the job at the bottom) and parallely post database validation i would want to add the files in tfilelist1 to the targetfolder(using tfilecopy)....so there are 2 steps check if the filename & size exists already in database if not add an entry into the db and copy to target folder

Comment: And the SPECIAL case is where i am not getting an clear way ,so lets say if the filesize is alone different for the same filename which was previously loaded,then in that case the entry would be added in dbase and correspondingly the old file would also be existing in the target folder,so only if the filesize differs here i am renaming the file to _modified.csv and creating a new entry in the target folder,makes sense?

Comment: Ok i think pieced the parts of the puzzle together,i have a quick question,how do i create version1,2,3 and so on for every new updated file that i receive and i dont want to keep overwriting onto the filename_modified.csv format even if the same file is received 3rd or 4th,5th time and so on?Howdo i auto-increment the filename_count format? like filename_modified1.csv ,filename_modified2.csv like that?